# Using proxy with InstaBot in Python giving csrf token error

Tags: python, proxy, bots, instagram, http-status-code-429

I am trying to create a bot to upload photos on instagram but after a couple of executions i'm getting the 429 Error.
I want to use a proxy to bypass this

I am using the below code

```
from instabot import Bot
bot = Bot()
time.sleep(5)
bot.login(username = 'username',password = 'password',proxy="138.204.145.39:3128")
```

I have tried multiple proxies and it is always throwing the csrf token error

Comment: Hi, I am getting the same. Did you find a way to fix it?